# In Firefox, button is deactivated unless I tab off or click out of the last input box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firefox, web

In the example picture, you can see that I clicked and filled all three boxes but in Firefox I have to either press tab or click somewhere on the page for the button to activate.

What's going on?

[image: deactivated button even though all three fields are filled out]

Code for the year drop down and button:

```html
<select id="form_dob_year" name="dobYear" ng-model="selectedYear" aria-labelledby="dob_label" ng-change="dateComparison(); UpdateNumberOfDays()" ng-options="year for year in Years" required ng-class="{ 'error-border' : (setUp.dobMonth.$invalid || setUp.dobDay.$invalid || setUp.dobYear.$invalid) && !(setUp.dobMonth.$pristine && setUp.dobDay.$pristine && setUp.dobYear.$pristine) && (setUp.dobMonth.$touched && setUp.dobDay.$touched && setUp.dobYear.$touched)}"><option value="" translate-default="Year"></option>
</select>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <button id="button" class="button" type="submit" ng-click="buttonEvent()"ng-disabled="setUp.$invalid" translate-default="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are your inputs part of a defined form using `<form name="formName"` or `ng-form`?

Comment: Can you show us the full code (html and js), or even better, create [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/)?